# Git aliases : use common function in various diff aliases

Tags: git, alias, git-config

I want to write some aliases for some diff commands in git. I have a few requirements :

1. Only one revision is given and it is always inferred that you want to diff against its parent.
2. If a revision is a merge, then the command fails.
3. It is optionally possible (but not required) to pass either a folder or a file to limit the diff to.
4. Options are the usual : `--stat`, `--compact-summary`, `--name-only`. I want short aliases that allow me to quickly choose either option. For example : `git dps <rev>` for `--stat`, `git dpn <rev>` for `--name-only`, `git dpc` for `--compact-summary` and simply `git dp <rev>` for no option.

What are any suggestions ? I wanted to write a common function that checks wether a revision is a merge, but couldn't. Otherwise I was able to write the following which fulfills 1 and 3, and 4 if I write multiple versions of this :

```
dp<option-differentiator> = "!f() { git diff <insert-option> $1^ $1 -- $2; }; f"
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. And most likely you have either register all possible aliases you're going to use (that would simplify all commands every alias refers to), or move the discriminator switch as `$1` right to `f()` and `shift` the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an executable file named `git-<something>` in your path, you can execute it as if `git` had a `<something>` subcommand.

---

You can write a regular script file, name it `git-dp` and place it on your path.

You will then be able to call :

```
git dp [s|n|c] <rev>
```